# Possible reasons for an airflow backfill to interrupt after some DAG runs

Tags: python, airflow

I've added a task to one my DAGs, and have been trying to `airflow backfill` the task on the dates when it did not exist yet. I gave my command a --task_regex, a --start_date and an --end_date argument.
Everything seemed to work well but Airflow crashed with this error after backfilling for some of the DAG runs:

```
[2019-06-06 12:13:25,378] {jobs.py:2521} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 185, in backfill
    delay_on_limit_secs=args.delay_on_limit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 3724, in run
    job.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 198, in run
    self._execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 2441, in _execute
    raise AirflowException(err)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: ---------------------------------------------------
Some task instances failed:
%s
```

Does someone know what could have happened? Should I have launched this backfilling in background?
(Airflow 1.9)

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to what is described in this issue 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1482?attachmentSortBy=dateTime
when they are using the celery executor.

Had similar problems when using localexecution, where the backfill would stop if any currently scheduled backfill tasks failed. Were also running airflow 1.9.